# Display custom taxonomy child terms with category image on parent term archive

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a CPT with a custom taxonomy called 'equipment_cat'. I'm currently displaying the subcategories of a category on the category archive using the following code:

```
<?php
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
    if ($term->parent == 0) {
wp_list_categories('taxonomy=equipment_cat&depth=1&show_count=0&title_li=&child_of=' . $term->term_id);
    } else {
wp_list_categories('taxonomy=equipment_cat&show_count=0&title_li=&child_of=' . $term->parent);
    }
?>
```

I'm using [Taxonomy Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/) plugin to attach an image to each category. I've created a custom page template to display all top level categories with their images using this code:

```
<?php
    $terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array(
      'taxonomy'=>'equipment_cat',
      'image_size' => 'medium',
      'term_args' => 'parent=0',
      'order' => 'ASC' ,
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'count'   => 2) );

    foreach( (array) $terms as $term){
        echo '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">';
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '">' .      wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'medium' ) . '</a>' . '<h3>'. sprintf(__('%s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '</h3>';
        echo '<div class="description">';
        echo $term->description;
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

I would like to display the sub categories of a category in the category archive but also include the image that are attached to the subcategory.

Comment: My guess would be to use get_post_meta or something similar, to find the call for the image, but since we don't know how it is saved, then it is hard to say.